# Javascript Ajax save result of onreadystatechange in global variable

Tags: javascript, onreadystatechange

I'm trying to write a script to retrieve a WOEID and interface with the Yahoo Weather API.  I'm constructing a URL based on latitude and longitude values from stuff in a database I'm using, and can do this perfectly fine.

However, when it comes to storing that URL as a string that I can use in other functions, I'm having trouble.  After some initial reading it seems to be a problem to do with onreadystatechange and scope, but I can't seem to get my head around it to be able to store my variable.

Here is my code so far:

```
 //<![CDATA[

var latitude = "";
var longitude = "";
var yahooAppID = "";
var yql = "";

//example yahoo request
//http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=38.898717,+-77.035974&gflags=R&appid=SKUTk24k


function getLatLng() {
    var routeID = 5;
    var get = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    get.open('POST','process.php', true)
    get.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    get.send('command=fetch&rid='+routeID);
    get.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(get.readyState==4 && get.status == 200) {
                os = eval('(' + get.responseText + ')');
                latitude = os.start.lat;
                longitude = os.start.lng;
                //var yql = 'select * from flickr.places where lat='+latitude+' and lon='+longitude;
                yql = "select * from flickr.places where lat=" +latitude+ " and lon="+longitude;
            }
            document.write(yql);
        }
        document.write(yql);
    }


function test() {
    getLatLng();
}
//]]>
```

The first `document.write(yql);` seems to produce the correct string, but the second does not, so I know that the value has not stuck.

Thanks in advance if anyone can help.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not looking at a scoping issue — rather, a timing issue. AJAX requests (at least the way you've configured it) happen asynchronously, so the rest of your script will execute while the AJAX request is loading. So `yql` won't be updated until the very end.

Also, warning: by the time the request completes, you can no longer use `document.write`. Use `alert()` or DOM manipulation.

Life cycle looks like this:

1. Script is executed normally
2. Anonymous function is bound to `onreadystatechange`
3. readyState changes from "unsent" to "headers received" to "loading" to "done". Your function gets called *every* time, but you only set `yql` when the ready state is "done."
4. readyState is done, and you generate `yql`.

So, just call your processing function from inside the if:

```
if(get.readyState==4 && get.status == 200) {
        os = get.responseXML;
        //find lat + lng
        yql = "select * from flickr.places where lat=" +latitude+ " and lon="+longitude;
        process(yql); //here!
}



function process(yql) {
   alert(yql);     //do something more useful eventually
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qA8py/)